# Axios Get Request W/ Header Not Working

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to make a get request with Axios to an API that requires an API key as a header, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I am getting two errors in the console. 1: xhr.js:178 OPTIONS https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1 403 (Forbidden).
2: Failed to load https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
I'm using React -- Thanks for looking

```
const API_KEY = "*******";
class List extends Component {
  state = {
    legislators: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1", {
        headers: { 'Authorization': API_KEY }
      })
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is most probably a CORS issue.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than the site currently in use.

You can read more on CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

To bypass CORS you can use [CORS-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/). The documentation for which is provided [here](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere)

The header should be provided in the format `X-API-Key: PROPUBLICA_API_KEY` and not `'Authorization': API_KEY` (refer [docs](https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/#authentication))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have changed the header to match the docs and still no luck, when I prefix with CORS-anywhere I get a 403(forbidden) error